# How to fix React app dependencies failing on AWS?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, dependencies, package.json

I recently deployed an app to AWS. Locally it's working okay with the dependencies I have installed. AWS installs the dependencies on the cloud (see here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/nodejs-platform-packagejson.html), so I don't have to install them and then upload them, so I know my `node_modules` isn't getting uploaded and having some issue.

Here's my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "cookbook",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/icons": "^3.0.2",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "material-ui": "^1.0.0-beta.47",
    "material-ui-icons": "^1.0.0-beta.36",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-google-login": "^5.0.4",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.8",
    "ts-pnp": "^1.0.1",
    "typescript": "^3.4.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^3.9.3"
  }
}
```

The error I get is in regards to `material-ui/core/styles`. Then it proceeds to give me another ERROR saying:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve '@material-ui/core'
```

When I run `npm start` locally it's working okay. The only thing I can think of is peer dependencies...I had a heck of a time getting material-ui installed and it wouldn't install everything simply from `npm install`. I'm wondering if AWS is having the same problem? I had to try to install peer dependencies manually on my local machine. It gave me trouble for a while but I finally got everything installed I needed. I can't help but feel AWS might be having the same issue...any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not sure what the issue was but I deleted my package.json and reinstalled all my packages from scratch using `npm install --save` on every package npm bugged me about when I tried to run my app. Here was my resulting package.json:

```
{
  "name": "cookbook",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^3.9.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^3.0.2",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-google-login": "^5.0.4",
    "react-scripts": "^2.1.8"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

There are some slight changes. Since I installed everything from scratch there ended up being some unnecessary packages that were removed. Also, I noticed that when re-installing the material packages were upgraded and not beta. I'm not sure why they were beta versions originally. I have a hunch maybe that had something to do with it.

If anyone has some actual insight into why the changes would have worked, I'd sure like to hear it. Thanks.